# Saving data to database without reload using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, http, post

I have a form in which I user can insert multiple inputs fields and save to database using ajax

Here is my form HTML

```
<form id="paramsForms" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{ method_field('POST') }}

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

                <div class="card mt-5 col-md-12 animated bounceInDown myForm" id="multiple-container">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4>Bidders Information</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body" id="add_info">
                        <div id="dynamic_container">

                            <small id="bidder">Bidder 1</small>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidders_name[]" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mt-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="atribute name" name="params_name[]"  class="form-control"/>
                                <input type="number" placeholder="atribute value" name="params_value[]" class="form-control"/>
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm moreinput_field" id="add_more_input">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-footer" id="card-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="add_more"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add</a>
                        <!-- <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right submit_btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Submit</button> -->
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
        </dvi>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Here is js for submitting inputs

```
$("#paramsForms").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route("parameters.store") }}',
        method: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend:function() {
            $("#save").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert('Data successfull saved');
        },
        error:function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            alert('Data not saved');
        }
    })   
})
```

Here are my route settings

```
Route::get('/parameters', "ParameterController@index");
Route::post('parameters/store', 'ParameterController@store')->name('parameters.store');
```

Here is store function in my controller to save data

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $rules = array(
            'params_name.*'  => 'required',
            'params_value.*'  => 'required',
            'bidders_name.*' => 'required'
        );
        $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if($error->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'error'  => $error->errors()->all()
            ]);
        }

        $params_name = $request->params_name;
        $params_value =$request->params_value;
        $bidders_name =$request->bidders_name;

        for($count = 0; $count < count($params_name); $count++)
        {
            $data = array(
                'params_name'   => $params_name[$count],
                'params_value'  => $params_value[$count],
                'bidders_name'  => $bidders_name[$count],

            );
            $insert_data[] = $data; 
        }

        Parameter::store($insert_data);
        return response()->json([
            'success'  => 'Data Added successfully.'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now when the user clicks the Save button to submit the data I get the following error.

```
message: "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE."
```

I tried most SO solutions provided by other fellas, but I still get the error

what am I doing wrong in my codes?

Comment: did you tried to change method: "POST" to method: "GET"

Comment: Maybe try putting a `/` forward slash on your routes, both on your ajax and web.php. And as for the url on ajax try changing it to `/parameters/store`

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi why I should do that while I want to use POST?

Comment: `{{ method_field('POST') }}` remove this from form. you're already passing it in form attribute as well in ajax your method is post so it's not required.

Comment: try to clear your route cache `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: @SaeedM. i get this ` LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.`

Comment: @Steven still the same :(

Comment: Have you another route name called "parameters.store" ? It seems another route definition overriding your route

Comment: php artisan route:list check and see if you have something else in parameters.store

Comment: why does your parameters show @inde and not index? and change both routes from parameters to /parameters. set the prefix in front

Comment: Try to remove this line `{{ method_field('POST') }}` !!

Comment: I suggest inspecting and making sure that the form is actually `POST`ing to the correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery post seems to be incorrect.

try replacing `method: "POST"` with `type: 'POST'`

see: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

also you do not need `{{ method_field('POST') }}` it is used for PUT, DELETE, PATCH request which isn't supported by some browsers.

Comment: I'm completely unsure if `method` is an alias of `type` though. Haven't touched jQuery in years.

Comment: `type` was used in the older version of jquery. The newer version has `method` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change your route order:

```
Route::post('parameters/store', 'ParameterController@store')->name('parameters.store');
Route::get('/parameters', "ParameterController@index");
```

Comment: It wouldn't matter as they have different URI, one has a `/store` while the other one doesn't.

Comment: First not working, second Can you explain why I should do that??

Comment: I think you have a cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but have you tried not using nested route name ? Or at least try defining your routes like this if you really want the nested name :

```php
Route::prefix('parameters')->name('parameters.')->group(function () {
    Route::post('store', 'ParameterController@store')->name('store');
    Route::get('/', "ParameterController@index");
});
```

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-name-prefixes

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```html
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

in the head of your html document and

then you have to add some codes in your jQuery:

```js
$("#paramsForms").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({

            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route("parameters.store") }}',
        method: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend:function() {
            $("#save").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert('Data successfull saved');
        },
        error:function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            alert('Data not saved');
        }
    })   
})
```

Comment: can you explain why we need to add token on meta tag?

Answer (score -1):

Makes changes from:

```
<form id="paramsForms" method="POST">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        {{ method_field('POST') }}
```

to

```
<form id="paramsForms">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
```

and try. Also, if it doesnt' work, run `php artisan route:cache` to clear route cache.